# GHC API - How to dynamically load Haskell code from a compiled module using GHC 7.2?

Tags: haskell, module, ghc, dynamic-loading, ghc-api

I have an existing Haskell function that uses the GHC API to dynamically load compiled code from a module. It is based on the code from the blog post [Dynamic Compilation and Loading of Modules in Haskell](http://www.bluishcoder.co.nz/2008/11/dynamic-compilation-and-loading-of.html).

The code works fine in GHC 7.0, but had to be slightly modified to compile in GHC 7.2, because the GHC API changed.

The code now throws a runtime error in GHC 7.2:

```
mkTopLevEnv: not a home module (module name):(function name)
```

The code is

```
evalfuncLoadFFI String moduleName, 
                String externalFuncName, 
                String internalFuncName = do

  result <- liftIO $ defaultRunGhc $ do
    dynflags <- GHC.getSessionDynFlags
    _ <- GHC.setSessionDynFlags dynflags
    m <- GHC.findModule (GHC.mkModuleName moduleName) Nothing

--------------------------------------------------------    
-- The following code works fine in GHC 7.0.4:
--
--  GHC.setContext [] [(m, Nothing)]
--
-- This new code attempts to set context to the module, 
-- but throws an error in GHC 7.2:
--
    (_,oi) <- GHC.getContext
    GHC.setContext [m] oi
--------------------------------------------------------

    fetched <- GHC.compileExpr (moduleName ++ "." ++ externalFuncName)
    return (Unsafe.Coerce.unsafeCoerce fetched :: [LispVal] -> IOThrowsError LispVal)
  defineVar env internalFuncName (IOFunc result)
```

For reference, the full code is available online in [FFI.hs (github.com)](https://github.com/justinethier/husk-scheme/blob/master/hs-src/Language/Scheme/FFI.hs).

Does anyone have any idea how to fix or work around this problem?

Also, could this be caused by the new Safe Haskell changes in GHC 7.2, or is it just due to modifications to the GHC API?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The current module context is reserved for modules that are currently being compiled, i.e. when you specify modules in the context, they must explicitly *not* be external.

Instead, you should specify the wanted module as an import, in the second argument of `setContext`. This can be done like so:

```
GHC.setContext []
  -- import qualified Module
  [ (GHC.simpleImportDecl . GHC.mkModuleName $ moduleName)
    { GHC.ideclQualified = True
    }
  -- -- import qualified Data.Dynamic
  -- , (GHC.simpleImportDecl . GHC.mkModuleName $ "Data.Dynamic")
  --   { GHC.ideclQualified = True
  --   }
  ]
fetched <- GHC.compileExpr $ moduleName ++ "." ++ externalFuncName
return . unsafeCoerce $ fetched
-- or:
-- fetched <- GHC.dynCompileExpr $ moduleName ++ "." ++ externalFuncName
-- return . fromDynamic (error "Illegal type cast") $ fetched
```

**PS**: it might be a good idea to use `GHC.dynCompileExpr` instead, so that you can avoid the `unsafeCoerce`. You must add a qualified import for `Data.Dynamic` in the context for it to work, but a [`Data.Dynamic.Dynamic`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Dynamic.html#t%3aDynamic) value is generally nicer to work with, since you can handle type errors more gracefully. I've added the code for that as comments in the above code.

---

**Update**

And here is the syntax for GHC 7.4.1:

```
GHC.setContext  
  -- import qualified Module
  [ GHC.IIDecl $ 
    (GHC.simpleImportDecl . GHC.mkModuleName $ moduleName)
    {GHC.ideclQualified = True}
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
GHC.setContext [] [(m,Nothing)]
```

(from [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521129/importing-a-known-function-from-an-already-compiled-binary-using-ghcs-api-or-h))

Comment: See my recent edit; this is the code I am using for GHC 7.0. But the API changed in GHC 7.2 and 7.4...