# Does GHC API dynamic loading work only with modules from installed packages?

Tags: haskell, dynamic-loading, ghc-api

I try to follow the way described in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521129/importing-a-known-function-from-an-already-compiled-binary-using-ghcs-api-or-h).

I have `ExampleModule.o` and `ExampleModule.hi` files in the working directory and I try to load `ExampleModule.f` function. But I get error message (with verbosity level set to 3):

```
Failed to load interface for `ExampleModule':
  locations searched:
    ExampleModule.hs
    ExampleModule.lhs
```

The `packageIdString (thisPackage dynflags)` is `"main"`.

I suppose that's because I can only load modules from installed packages. Am I right? Is there a way to load a function dynamically from standalone object file, just like [`load`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/plugins/1.5.1.4/doc/html/System-Plugins-Load.html#v:load) function from `plugins` does, but with GHC API?

Comment: What does it say with the `-v` option?

Comment: It seems like it's searching for the source file, and not for the compiled ones.