# Using Hint to dynamically compile and load Haskell

Tags: haskell, hint, dynamic-compilation

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521129/importing-a-known-function-from-an-already-compiled-binary-using-ghcs-api-or-h) post, the discussion makes it seem like Haskell's Hint package can compile source code and load compiled programs (as opposed to interpreting a source file).
However, I don't really see any of that functionality in the API, and that post seems to have gone dead before answering the question.
So... how do you do it, or did I get the wrong impression?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably want the `plugins` package and not `hint`.

Comment: Based on my recent experience, I think `plugins` is broken.

Comment: Plugins is not broken completely, just undocumented and very difficult to use.
There are a ton of gotcha's, but once you figure it out I think it works more or less stably.